# AOP issues with @Transactional

Tags: spring-security, aop, aspectj, transactional

In my spring 5 MVC application, I have enabled AOP in my dispatcher servlet xml using `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />`. 
The controller classes' methods are annotated with `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SOME_AUTH')")`.

If I enable AOP, the hasAuthority() method calls the database to check the permission.

If I disable AOP, the hasAuthority() method does not call the database to check the permission, instead it checks it from context itself.

(This is my observation by enabling the logs at level TRACE. With AOP enabled, I see the queries to check the permission on my console. With AOP disabled, I do not see the queries on my console.)

When hasAuthority() starts interacting with the database, I have to annotate the controller method with `@Transactional` so that the current database session is closed. If I don't do so, the application stops working after a few successful requests because all the connections are consumed as the db session is not closed.

Now the problem is that I don't want to annotate all the methods of the controller(`with @PreAuthorize()`) with @Transactional.
Also, I do not want to move all the hasAuthority() methods to a custom SecurityUtil class and then replace hasAuthority() with `@securityUtil.hasAuthority()`.

Is there any other way I can achieve this without using @Transactional on my controller methods OR is there some way by which I can force Spring Security to check the permission from the context and not from the database when AOP is enabled?

**UPDATE**

The query generated by hasAuthority() is as below:

```
select this_.type as y0_, this_.key_id as y1_ from permission_master this_ where this_.status=? and this_.key_id in()
```

The class SecurityExpressionRoot.java has the method hasAuthority() which calls below methods in sequence:
hasAuthority() -> hasAnyAuthority() -> hasAnyAuthorityName -> getAuthoritySet() -> roleHierarchy.getReachableGrantedAuthorities()

In our code base, the call roleHierarchy.getReachableGrantedAuthorities() was overridden so I added @Transactional to the overridden call and solved my issue. But my question is why does enabling AOP makes hasAuthority() call the database and disabling AOP does not.

Comment: Yes, it is not from Spring security. We use Hibernate. But the question is why AOP is making spring security hit the database.
Debugging the source code and referencing https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/, I figured out that spring security has AccessDecisionManager.decide() which gets invoked for authorization. In my case, the decide() method (concrete impl AffirmativeBased.java) gets called twice when AOP is enabled. This method is invoked by AbstractSecurityInterceptor(FilterSecurityInterceptor and MethodSecurityInterceptor).

Comment: With AOP disabled, only FilterSecurityInterceptor calls the decide() method. MethodSecurityInterceptor finally invokes RoleHierarchy.getReachableGrantedAuthorities() which calls the db.
So I am not able to understand why AOP is causing an extra interceptor MethodSecurityInterceptor to come into play.